# SEO To Do's : A complete SEO To Do list

Tags: seo

Hey guys i am new to SEO , i have done SEO for a couple of sites and basically here is my understanding of the to-do's i have to do :

On page SEO :

1. XML sitemap
2. robots.txt
3. custom 404 page.
4. htaccess that redirects to http or www
5. check page speed . 
   6   Site structure
   -- One H1 tag
   -- Minimum One or Two H2 tag missing
   -- images alt tag
   -- Navigation link and  tag link tittle missing.
6. Google map address was not there, but it’s been created now.
7. Meta tag analysis
   -- Title should be 10-50 characters,
   -- Description should be less than 150 characters.
   -- Keywords should be below 20 words,

Off page  SEO :

1. citations
2. backlinks.

Is this all i need to do ? i know the off page SEO takes time and tricks and good marketing skills and is not just all about submiting your URL to backlink farms .

Am i missing anything important here ?

Thank you.

Alex-Y.